# wsdl2swift get only nil as result, connection Result is OK

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using http://wsdl2swift.com/ to create an iOS Swift JSON Client who is calling an asmx-WebService.

Everything works great, i can build the connection, receive the result JSON-String inside the response XML, and it is printed inside the libraries "makeSoapConnection"-Function.

But if i call

```
let client = SyedAbsarClient()
let gam = GetAllBla()
gam.cpMyId = "12"

client.opGetAllBla(gam){(response: GetAllBlaResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in   
   print(response?.cpGetAllBlaResult)
}
```

i only get "nill"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on the website, the utility is still under progress, For now, it returns the actual xml response that you can parse

```
        print(response?.xmlResponseString)
```