# Wsdl2Swift unable to make a connection

Tags: swift, soap, wsdl

I used wsdl2swift to consume a soap webservice but I cannot get any response. I tried to debug and it stops inside this function.

```
self.makeSoapConnection(soapUrl, soapAction: "", soapMessage: soapMessage, soapVersion: "1", className:"validateResponse", completionHandler: { (syedabsarObj:SyedAbsarObjectBase?, error: NSError? )->Void in completionHandler(syedabsarObj  as? ValidateResponse,error) })
```

Specifically on this line:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34085882/wsdl2swift-get-only-nil-as-result-connection-result-is-ok